# How to find the elements of each bin after using the histcount function

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am using histcount method for categorizing my array data into separate bins. 
Here is the simple code I used.

```
[N,edges] = histcounts(score,5)
```

where 'score' is an array of integers. How to display all the elements of each bin other than the comparing method. Is there any built-in method available in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4):

The **third output of [`histcounts`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)** gives just that:

```
>> data = [0.81470.9058 0.12700.91340.6324 .09750.2785 0.5469];
>> [N,edges,bin] = histcounts(data,5)
N =
     2     1     1     1     3
edges =
         0    0.1900    0.3800    0.5700    0.7600    0.9500
bin =
     5     5     1     5     4     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

`[N,edges] = histcounts(score,n)` orders score from lowest to highest and places score into n=5 bins.  `N` is a vector indicating how many objects are in each bin, and edges defines the endpoints of each bin.  So, if you want to back out what is in the first bin, you order score then count the number of objects in the first bin using `N(1)`.

To order score type `sorted_score = sort(score)`.

To view the first N(1) elements of this, type `sorted_score(1:N(1))`.

Output `sorted_score(N(i-1)+1:N(i))`, `N(0) = 0`, is a sub-vector of score that displays all elements of score in bin `i`, as requested.

Edit: Clarified output.

Comment: I don't use `edges` to index the array.  I use the number of elements, `N(i)`, in bin `i` to back out the elements in bin `i`.